# TextView not displaying data from xml file

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to retrieve some data from my xml file. Below is the code which should be working but in this case it doesn't. I am not getting errors but data just doesn't gets displayed.Please review this code and tell me what's wrong here.
(I am trying to look at an id, if it matches a certain digit than display text)
Thanks.

```
String stringXmlContent;
    try {
     stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
     tv.setText(stringXmlContent);
   } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)throws XmlPullParserException, IOException

{
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
     String attVal = null;
      String desc;
     Resources res = activity.getResources();
     XmlResourceParser xrp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
     try {
            xrp.next();
            int eventType = xrp.getEventType();
              while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
               {
                  if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
                    {
                     stringBuffer.append(" ");
                    }
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {

                  if(xrp.getName().equals("Number")){

                     attVal =  xrp.getAttributeValue(0); 
                  }   

                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                {

                   if(xrp.getName().equals("Description") && attVal.equals("2")){


                     stringBuffer.append(" " + xrp.getText());
                  }   

                }

              }


        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuffer.toString();
```